# Calculate larger part of $\phi$ from number

Tags: geometry

Say I have a number, $667$.  How would I find the larger half of $\phi$ from this number?

For example, a box $1000$px wide divided by $\phi$ would make two boxes roughly
$618$px by $382$px.

Well if I'm starting from $667$ as the larger half, how to I find the first number that was to split the boxes?

In our example, $\phi$ was found by doing
$1000 \cdot 0.618...$
or
$1000 / 618$ would give same result.

But if $618$ was the only number known, how are the other two found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just do $\frac {667}{0.618}\approx 1079$  Normally $\phi$ refers to $\frac 12(1+\sqrt 5)\approx 1.618 \approx \frac 1{0.618}$ so your use is the inverse of the usual one.

Comment: Thanks, exactly the answer to my question.   Not sure why someone closed it as off topic as its straight up math question.